# current time android xml

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to declare the current time in a xml file for android.
I want to set the minDate of a Datepicker in layout/acticity.xml.

I want that the minDate of my datePicker is the current date.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This can't be done in XML, but can be done pretty easily in the Java side of things. Android does not allow you to set the minimum date to the exact current time, so simply use:

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. What happen if I set to new Date().getTime() ?

Comment: Why -1000 (1 second before)? wouldn't it be enough `datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());`?

Comment: @Alex I distinctly recall an old question here saying it wasn't possible. Let me try it out for myself and get back to you.

Comment: @Alex Confirmed. I just made a test project, and `System.currentTimeMillis()` results in an error. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/nnM5mXfN) the pastebin

Comment: @ArtooDetoo One second is required as Android throws a fit if you set it to the current time.

Comment: @Alex It seems to be done to avoid conflict between a (I'm guessing default) selected date and the minimum date. The exception I got is [here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/core/java/android/widget/CalendarView.java#955) in the Android source.

Comment: I finished my votes for today, but tomorrow I must remember to add +1. That's really a good trick!